# Java TreeMap with keys that do not implement Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I noticed that I can create an instance of the Java 8 TreeMap<K,V> (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) as

```
TreeMap<Object, Integer> foo = new TreeMap<Object, Integer>();
```

But why does this not generate a compilation error, seeing as Object does not implement Comparable, and I did not supply a Comparator? How is the TreeMap supposed to sort the keys without any way to know what order they're in?

Comment: Because keys don't have to be `Comparable`, if you supply a `Comparator` when creating the `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why no compile time error

`TreeMap` could have been declared as:

```
public class TreeMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>,V>
    extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
```

Note the `K extends Comparable<? super K>` constraint. This would totally disallow you from using non-`Comparable` types such as `Object` as the key type. However, sometimes you *do* want to use a non-`Comparable` type, and provide an explicit comparator. You'd totally disallow those cases, which are quite valid, if you added that constraint.

What about only adding the constraint when you are not providing a comparator explicitly, i.e. making the parameterless constructor available only when the key type implements `Comparable`? There are languages that have syntax that allows you to do this. Unfortunately, Java isn't one of those languages :(

In the end they decided that it was better to allow you to always use non-`Comparable` types as the key type (and crash at runtime), than to *not* allow you to use custom comparators + non-`Comparable` key types.

#### Why your code does not crash at runtime

(Though you didn't specifically ask about this, I thought I should explain this too, because you seem to think that Java still has some way of sorting the non-`Comparable` objects, presumably your code didn't crash. The truth is, Java *doesn't* know how to sort your non-`Comparable` objects.)

Your code only creates the map. At runtime, the generics are erased, so it can't possibly know that you are creating a map with non-`Comparable` keys.  It's only when you add non-`Comparable` keys into it, that it crashes:

```
TreeMap<Object, Integer> foo = new TreeMap<Object, Integer>();
foo.put(new Object(), 1); // crashes
```

Plus, you can still add *comparable* keys to a `TreeMap<Object, Integer>`.

Comment: I think it's a design flaw. They could have handled both safely with static factory methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use another constructor that requires `Comparator`.

- [`public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-)

> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator. All keys inserted into the map must be *mutually comparable* by the given comparator

For example, I compare `Object` instances based on their `toString` method, but the final implementation is up to you. Both comparators below are the same:

- ```
  Comparator<Object> comparator = (l, r) -> l.toString().compareTo(r.toString());
  ```
- ```
  Comparator<Object> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Object::toString);
  ```

Pass the `Comparator` into the constructor:

```
TreeMap<Object, Integer> foo = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```